ROS2 Humble Python composable node
I have a python node ( ROS2 Humble), that I would like to convert it to a composable node.
I could not find any documentation on the python equivalent to the rclcpp_components_register_node cmake command.
I would assume that I would need to adjust the python code of the node as well as the setup.py file.
I did many trials in the node.py and setup.py as per some recommendations from ChatGpt
for all trials, I got the following error when launching:
[ERROR] [bar.container]: Could not find requested resource in ament index
[ERROR] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Failed to load node 'foo_node' of type 'foo_node' in container '/bar/container': Could not find requested resource in ament index
It would be great if you could help me figure this out.
Thanks.
